# Modify Silverlight Resource in VisualState

Tags: silverlight, visualstatemanager, brush, staticresource

I am wondering if there is an easy way to modify some kind of shared resource (i.e. a Brush) of a control between different VisualStates. For example, I would like to define a Brush to use as both the Background of a Border and the Fill of a different Rectangle. In a different VisualState I would like to change this background Brush in one place (the resource) and have it reflected in all elements using the resource.

I am not sure if resources can really be referenced by Name (not Key) for the TargetName of the Storyboard in the VisualState.

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do in XAML:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="SilverlightApplication.MainPage"
Width="200" Height="200">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Background" x:Key="Background" Color="Black" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Red">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Color)">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Red"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Border Background="{StaticResource Background}" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource Background}" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have a feeling because these are StaticResources in Silverlight they are only loaded once and can not be changed. I know WPF has some concept of DynamicResources. Is there any way to achieve this type of behavior in Silverlight without having to redefine my brush in all elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamicResources unfortunately don't exist in Silverlight.

Some people use Bindings.

There's a sneaky way to simulate the experience within a single UserControl that you might want to try.

All that's happening in the code below is that the Storyboard animates a single rectangle's Fill, which is then bound to the other Fill's in the UserControl by using Element binding. The source rectangle doesn't need to be visible for this to work.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSilverlightStuff.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSilverlightStuff"            
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background" Color="Black" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Red">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="trickyRectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" x:Name="trickyRectangle" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <Border Background="{Binding Fill, ElementName=trickyRectangle}" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill, ElementName=trickyRectangle}" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,231,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here's the C# button click code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Red", true);
}
```

It's not as elegant as a DynamicResource, but it works in some cases.

Comment: I ended up exposing Brush properties to bind to on my view model to accomplish this, but I see how this trick would work as well so I'll mark it as the answer. Both approaches feel a little dirty, but that's silverlight for you. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything obvious. Thanks!